# Xalan 2.7.1 Syntax Error: Could not compile stylesheet

Tags: xslt, stylesheet, xalan

I'm having an odd problem when using pre-compiled XSLT stylesheets in my application.

When NOT using the pre-compiled option I get no errors.  When I enable pre-compiled stylesheets (translets) using Xalan, I am getting a few compilation errors.  This one is representative:

```
16:21:15,262 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-177) ERROR:  'Syntax error in 'not(@value = (preceding-sibling::CreateAsnCalloff)[@materialshipped = '0' or @value = 'NON-CALL OFF ASN']/@value)'.'    
16:21:15,262 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-177) FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'    
16:21:15,262 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-177) javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
```

The bit of XSLT that is causing the issue is:

```
<xsl:if test="not(@value = (preceding-sibling::CreateAsnCalloff)[@materialshipped = '0' or @value = '*NON-CALL OFF ASN*']/@value)">

    <OPTION value="{@cd}"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></OPTION>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<xsl:if test="not(@value = preceding-sibling::CreateAsnCalloff[@materialshipped = '0' or @value = '*NON-CALL OFF ASN*']/@value)">` instead.

Comment: I guess I should have added that what you have was my original code.  I added the () after reading another article that suggested that as a solution for another case.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6577667

But both produce the same error.